# General style with specific properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, controltemplate

I would like to have a dynamic `ToolTip` style that changes the foreground color based on the text of different string properties (in this code example, the string is `PosError`, but it could be any property name, and if the value is "Error", the `DataTrigger` is triggered.

As for now, I have to do it like this for each and every `TextBox`: Change the property binding of the `DataTrigger` and the text of the `ToolTip` (in this example, the string property is `PosExtreme`):

```
<TextBox 
    Width="150" 
    FontSize="25"
    MaxWidth="150"
    Name="posTab"
    TextAlignment="Center"
    Text="{Binding PosTabStrength, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <ToolTip.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PosError}" Value="Error">
                             <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                 <Setter Property="Foreground">
                                     <Setter.Value>
                                         <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                             <GradientStop Color="#F08080" Offset="0"/>
                                             <GradientStop Color="#F04080" Offset="1"/>
                                         </LinearGradientBrush>
                                      </Setter.Value>
                                  </Setter>
                              </DataTrigger.Setters>
                          </DataTrigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
                          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                          <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
                          <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                          <Setter Property="Foreground">
                              <Setter.Value>
                                  <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                      <GradientStop Color="#10F080" Offset="0"/>
                                      <GradientStop Color="#10B080" Offset="1"/>
                                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                              </Setter.Value>
                          </Setter>
                          <Setter Property="Template">
                              <Setter.Value>
                                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                                      <Border 
                                          CornerRadius="3"
                                          BorderThickness="1"
                                          Background="#CF001233"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                          Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                          Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                          <Border.Style>
                                              <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                                      <Setter.Value>
                                                          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                                              <GradientStop Color="#A0A0F0" Offset="0"/>
                                                              <GradientStop Color="#8080F0" Offset="1"/>
                                                              <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                                  <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                                              </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                          </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                      </Setter.Value>
                                                  </Setter>
                                              <Style.Triggers>
                                                  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
                                                      <BeginStoryboard>
                                                          <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                                              <DoubleAnimation 
                                                                  From="359"
                                                                  To="0"
                                                                  Duration="00:00:2" 
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"/>
                                                          </Storyboard>
                                                      </BeginStoryboard>
                                                  </EventTrigger>
                                              </Style.Triggers>
                                          </Style>
                                      </Border.Style>
                                  <ContentPresenter Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                              </Border>
                          </ControlTemplate>
                      </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
              </Style>
            </ToolTip.Style>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PosExtreme}"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

I would like to have the `ToolTip` style as `ResourceDictionary` file and not having to copy and paste the code and modify it for every `TextBox` with it's proper `ToolTip` style and `ToolTip` text.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main blocker for reusing the style are the bindings to concrete properties and the hard-coded `Error` string. You need to pass them from outside of the style and control template.

Your comparison of the `DataTrigger` can be encapsulated in a value converter that returns a boolean for the comparison of any bound property (`PosError`) with a fixed value (`Error`) passed as parameter.

```
public class ErrorComparisonToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value != null && parameter != null && value.Equals(parameter);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

In the `DataTrigger`, we do not bind a concrete property anymore, but the [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the `ToolTip`, which is a general purpose property.

> Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this element.

We assume that the comparison is done for us already and the `Tag` only contains the result `true` or `false`. This simplifies the `DataTrigger` and the dependency on `PosError` is gone.

Next, you can eliminate the `TextBlock` inside the `ToolTip`. [`ToolTip` is a `ContentControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltip?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and exposes a `Content` property. This content is shown automatically using the `ContentPresenter` inside the `ControlTemplate`. The dependency on `PosExtreme` is gone, too.

Move the style out in a resource dictionary in scope and create an instance of the converter, too.

```
<local:ErrorComparisonToBoolConverter x:Key="ErrorComparisonToBoolConverter"/>
```

```
<Style x:Key="MyToolTipStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.Setters>
              <Setter Property="Foreground">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                          <GradientStop Color="#F08080" Offset="0"/>
                          <GradientStop Color="#F04080" Offset="1"/>
                      </LinearGradientBrush>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
           </DataTrigger.Setters>
       </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                <GradientStop Color="#10F080" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#10B080" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Border 
                    CornerRadius="3"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Background="#CF001233"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#A0A0F0" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#8080F0" Offset="1"/>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                                From="359"
                                                To="0"
                                                Duration="00:00:2" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can reuse the style now and bind `PosExtreme` or any other property to the `Content` of `ToolTip` and the error property to `Tag`. The `Tag` binding uses the value converter to compare the bound value to the expected error code passed as `CommandParameter`.

```
<TextBox.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource MyToolTipStyle}"
             Content="{Binding PosExtreme}"
             Tag="{Binding PosError, ConverterParameter=Error, Converter={StaticResource ErrorComparisonToBoolConverter}}">
    </ToolTip>
</TextBox.ToolTip>
```

### Remarks

- The solution uses the `Tag` property to propagate the error property. In your example it works, but if you need to bind even more properties in the style or control template, you would have to create attached properties for each that you can bind instead of `Tag`. For a single property, `Tag` is just convenient.
- You could also create a custom `ToolTip` control that exposes dependency properties for the properties used in the style and control template instead of attached properties and do the comparison within.
- Depending on how your data items are implemented, you could eliminate the converter completely, by exposing a bool property, if that makes sense.